# Using the JUnitFlakyTestDataPublisher throws an AbstractMethodError "you must override contributeTestData"

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, maven-failsafe-plugin

I try to use the [rerunFailingTestsCount](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html) option to deal with flaky tests. In order to display these in the junit results, I use the [flaky test handler plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/flaky-test-handler) which would theoretically deal with displaying flaky tests

In my jenkins file this looks like

```
pipeline {    
  stages {
    stage('tests') {
      steps{
        // sh mvn verify here
      }

      post { 
        always {
          junit testResults: 'target/failsafe-reports/**/*.xml', testDataPublishers: [[$class:
            'JUnitFlakyTestDataPublisher']]
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the test run fine, flaky ones are repeated but when it comes to publishing the junit results, i get an

> Error when executing always post condition: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: you must override contributeTestData

Google wasn't very helpful, maybe someone here had the same problem and can help me or at least can confirm that this plugin works as pipeline script (there is a [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/flaky-test-handler-plugin/pull/10) regarding pipeline support, so I am not sure...)

Comment: Looks like JUnit changed the API in this [commit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/junit-plugin/commit/4ba5a491583157a90bfd472db5f657a60bb0c38e). The pull request you mentioned uses the new API, but was never merged due to a breaking build. Would be great if someone could have a look at that at some stage...

Comment: ok, good to know. the maintainers have no contact info and the repo does not allow issues... 
so my only way forward would be to create a pull request myself i guess

Comment: You could checkout the branch for that PR (mythsunwind:pipeline-support) and see if you can fix the remaining issues. But you should merge in the latest version of the main repository's master branch (jenkinsci:master) as well at that stage.

Comment: The PR has been merged now and should be released soon.

Comment: "soon"... is hasn't been released yet https://github.com/jenkinsci/flaky-test-handler-plugin/pull/10#issuecomment-498180430