# I enabled rerunFailingTestsCount Surefire feature. How do I configure Jenkins CI to show the rich test data?

Tags: java, jenkins, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I found out about rerunFailingTestsCount feature in Surefire ([commit](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/commit/fefaae7f0534a59f52c046a64c96987e8561dd48)). When a test fails, the runner tries to rerun it up to a specified number of times. If any of these reruns succeed, the test is considered PASSED, but FLAKY.

This feature implements extension to the JUnit XML report format, with additional attributes in the test result.

How can I configure Jenkins CI to meaningfully show the newly gained test data about my testing?

I would like to be able to monitor my flaky tests, so I can maintain general overview of what's going on, and later so I can prioritize fixing the ones that slow the build the most.

Build containing only flaky tests should be easily distinguishable from one that contained some failed tests, and from one containing only passing tests.

Comment: related: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27045/what-are-jenkins-plugins-to-monitor-and-handle-flaky-tests

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've found almost all the answers by yourself :)

The only thing that IMO is missing is Some Jenkins Plugin that indeed can show (visualize) the flaky tests based on surefire reports.

There is indeed [such a plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/flaky-test-handler) called Flaky Test Handler.

Disclaimer - I haven't tried it by myself but it seems that it can do the job. And it would have been my best bet to solve the issue.

An alternative would be creating a Jenkins plugin by yourself but it looks like a lot of hassle.

Yet another approach I can think of is creating a maven plugin that would parse the results of surefire plugin and create some additional HTML report and based on that information you could just visualize the HTML report in Jenkins (avoiding writing the jenkins plugin).

One last approach that I worked with a long time ago - is a maven plugin that again parses the results of surefire test and adds the result to some database (like mongo db or something). It can be invoked only in Jenkins so that Jenkins for supply some additional information like buildNumber.

Later on you could roll your own UI calling to mongo db and giving statistics over builds (like previous build had 10 flaky test, this build has 8 and so forth).

Comment: The Flaky Test Handler page says "Last released:4 years ago". Sounds like a long time. Is it safe to bring something this old into Jenkins?

Comment: Well, the choice is yours of course. Since its not really a production code, IMO it worth trying. Its always possible to roll your own version based on the source code of that plugin... Its possible that there are other plugins. I'm not a devops guy so my knowledge is rather limited in Jenkins.

Comment: Flaky Test Handler is currently broken, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402391/using-the-junitflakytestdatapublisher-throws-an-abstractmethoderror-you-must-ov